# Does ἕκτῃ mean "seventh" as well as in Genesis 2:2? Alpheios says that it means "sixth"

Tags: greek, numbers

I'm reading the LXX (Septuagint bible) and Alpheios Reading tools say that ἕκτῃ means "sixth" here when it's supposed to be "seventh" (according to the original Hebrew). Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cambridge](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/2-2.htm) explains this discrepancy:

> on the seventh day] Some misunderstanding arose in very early times in consequence of these words. Jealous for the sanctity of the Sabbath, men said, “No, not on the seventh day, but on the sixth day, God finished the work of creation.” So we find “on the sixth day” is the reading of the Samaritan, the LXX, and the Syriac Peshitto.

Similarly, Ellicott:

> The substitution, in the LXX. and Syriac, of the sixth for the seventh day, as that on which God ended His work, was probably made in order to avoid even the appearance of Elohim having put the finishing touches to creation on the Sabbath.

Answer (score 1):

The Hebrew original says very clearly: "And on the seventh day God ended his work which he had made; and he rested on the seventh day from all his work which he had made" (as correctly translated in the KJV). But the authors of the LXX evidently thought that this might imply that he continued to work up to and including the seventh day; according they corrected "on the seventh day" to "on the sixth day" (ἐν τῇ ἡμέρᾳ τῇ ἕκτῃ).